# Swapping file names in the same folder C++

Tags: c++, file-rename

I had two set of files in the same folder may or may not be equal in number. One set of files contains the word "rect" as a part of their names and the other one contain "circle" in their names.

I need to rename all the files which contain "rect" with "circle" by retaining the rest part of the file name and vice versa. What is the best method to do this?

Comment: I'd use [`std::rename`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename). Of course, you need the file names, which means enumerating the directory entries and some string substitutions. So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you have conflict problem for names. The solution is using an intermediate or a temporary.

If there is a conflict use [`std::tmpnam`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/tmpnam) to make a temorary name then [`std::rename`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename) it to that temp name, and so on...

Comment: ya..exactly conflict is my problem.Can you give a sample code.